# Consulta en Django a un modelo utilizando ORM?

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Curso(models.Model):
    fecha =  models.DateField()
    hora_inicio = models.TimeField()
    hora_fin = models.TimeField()
    capacidad_maxima = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=6)
    sede = models.ForeignKey(Sede)
    profesor =  models.ForeignKey(Profesor)
    estudiantes  =  models.ManyToManyField(Estudiante,blank=True)
    tipo_nivel  = models.CharField(max_length='2',default='xx')
    tipo_leccion = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    max_tipo = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=3)
    tipo_estudiante=models.ManyToManyField(Nivel,related_name='tipo_estudiante', blank=True)
```

Tengo este modelo, necesito hacer un Query que me devuelva solo los cursos que estén vacios o estén en el nivel del estudiante, adicional si existe mas cursos a la misma hora y están vacíos solo me devuelva los cursos varios o su vez el curso del nivel del estudiante para esa hora.

Comment: Primero creo que deberías agregar un campo que te diga cuál es la capacidad actual del curso

Answer (score 1):

Hombre, se me ocurre que para saber si hay cursos en el mismo horario puedes usar la siguiente función:

```
def is_courses_in_same_hour(self):
    courses = Curso.objects.all()
    for course in courses:
        if course.model.hora_inicio == self.hora_inicio and course.model.hora_fin == self.hora_fin:
            return True
```

Puedes jugar con los dos filtros, y crear una función que devuelve el queryset que necesitas.

Answer (score 1):

usa 'from django.db.models import Q' para realizar consultas 'or'.

Un ejemplo:

```
if form.cleaned_data['query']:
    query = form.cleaned_data['query']
    object_list = object_list.filter(
        Q(first_name__contains=query)
            | Q(last_name__contains=query)
            | Q(email__contains=query)
            | Q(identification_number__contains=query)
        ))
```